# Grant domain user access to a network folder by using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get domain user to pass their credentials to enable them to access a networked folder. To achieve that I decided to use PowerShell. Here is my code so far.

What the heck am I still missing here to achieve my goal? Thanks

```
Get-Credential

$credential = Get-Credential
$userName = $credential.UserName
$pass = $credential.Password


   if ( ($userName -eq 'USER' ) -and ((([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass)) -eq 'PA$$WORD')) ))
    {

    invoke-item \\SERVER\data\staff\fax}
```

Or is there some other more cleaner way of doing this. OK, if PowerShell is not the way to go about I'm open to other scripting ways of achieving this.

Comment: I am confused as to what you're trying to achieve here.  Are you trying to simply create a network share where people can log in and use or are you creating a script to authorize access to a share when they didn't have it before?

Comment: It's the later case. There is a Dispatch PC that is being used by many people under the same account but only one of those individuals has rights to access that folder. I don't want to map it as a drive but simply for the person to double click on the script that asks for their user name and password. Ideally I'd like for that folder to close after i.e. 10 minutes

Comment: If you want the end users to just double click and use, then Batch script will be the best option I think. Why you are so adamant about the usage of PowerShell itself. Even I am not that sure how about the timer thing of 10 minutes in PowerShell

Comment: Well, the timer would be nice but not necessary. Why PowerShell? Because I'm checking what I can do with it. I'd like to use PowerShell in this instance but I'm also open to other scripting suggestions.